# Fastest way to create range of tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the question suggests, I'm trying to create a range of tuples: 
`[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)...]` 
and I'm wondering what's the shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a  [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>> [(i,i) for i  in xrange(1,6)]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import repeat
zip(*repeat(xrange(1, n_tuples), 2))
```

Pros:

- **Fast:** Takes only ~56% of the time, expressions with list comprehensions need. IPython 
  reports: 10000 loops, best of 3: **92.8 us** per loop, with `n_tuples = 1000` (**list 
  comprehensions:** 10000 loops, best of 3: **165 us** per loop). (I'm highlighting this, 
  because it was specifically asked for the "fastest way").
- You can easily change the number of same elements in the tuples (by replacing the `2` with 
  the desired number).
- It's shorter (at least without the `import`).

Comment: Itertools is not really helpful here; compare eg. to `r = xrange(1, n_tuples); zip(r,r)`

Comment: Yeah, but what if you wanted to have tuples of the form `(1,1,1,1,1)`? You would need to do `zip(r,r,r,r,r)` which is not exactly DRY. I know that was not the question and in fact I only did this to limit the answer to one expression. Btw: to my own surprise, your solution is also only 1.7 us faster than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
number_of_tuples = 6
[(i, i) for i in range(number_of_tuples)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If by *range* you mean necessarily a list, look at the other answers here.

Otherwise, in case you just want to iterate through this or similar, consider using the comprehension as a generator without making a list out of it:

```
g = ((i, i) for i in xrange(1, 6))
```

and then later:

```
for a, b in g:
  print a, b
```

Creating that generator is definitely faster than creating a list.